# JQuery get the 9th character in a number

Tags: jquery, string, numbers

I have to get the 9th character in a barcode (10361510**7**00149) and when this char is equal to 7 it will set my checkbox as "checked".

Don't laugh, I wrote sth but of course it doesn't work. It's my first journey with JQuery :D

```
[event: , load,
    var bar = $(”#barcode”).val();
    var bars = bar.toString();
    var nine = bars.charAt(8);
    var nine_as_number = parseInt(nine);
    if (nine_as_number == 7) {
        $(’.c1540’).prop(’checked’, true);
    }
]
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code?

Comment: Would like to know, it doesn't mark the checkbox.

Comment: Please put  your html it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```js
$("span").each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().charAt(8) == 7)
        $(this).siblings("input").attr("checked", true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <span>10361510600149</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div>
    <span>10361510700149</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
<div>
    <span>10361510800149</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Comment: But it has to get the barcode, cause there are different, depend on case.

Comment: @MilenaJażdżyk I too get `barcode` value from html content. What is problem in my answer? Say that i update it.

Comment: Maybe cause in my html is line: <span id="barcode">10151510700129</span>

Comment: Nope, still doesn't mark checkbox. Don't know what is the problem.

Comment: It works, just put my line: $(’.c1540’).prop(’checked’, true);} Thank you very much @Mohammad